# How to get the values in between a particular range timestamps

Tags: sql-server, range, between, timestamp, datetime2

I have table in SQL Server 2008 called ,timestamplog `which contains one column of name LogTime of type`INTEGER`

The values are like this:

```
1350468610,
1350468000,
1350381600,
1350295810
```

I need the values in between `1350468609` and `1350468001`..

Please tell me how to query for those values.

I have try the following queries

```
select LogTime 
from timestamplog 
where LogTime between 1350468609 and 1350468001

select LogTime 
from timestamplog 
where LogTime >= '1350468610' and  LogTime <= '1350468000'

select LogTime 
from timestamplog 
where LogTime >= convert(decimal, 1350468610) and LogTime <= convert(decimal,1350468000)

select LogTime 
from timestamplog 
where LogTime >= convert(varchar, 12) and LogTime <= convert(varchar, 14)
```

But rows are not coming...

Actually the values in the table are the timestamps values stored as `INTEGER` in the table `TIMELOG`

IMP NOTE: Suppose if the values  like 12,13,14 into table ,the above queries are working fine. But when I am comparing number of length 10 the query doesn't retrieve any values

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 2):

Because 1350468001 is less than 1350468609, if you reverse the order, any of your queries would work. I'd go with...

```
select LogTime from timestamplog where LogTime between 1350468001 and 1350468609
```

which is an inclusive range.

Comment: +1 of course! :-) The query is right - but the `BETWEEN` values are flipped around :-) Good catch!

Comment: The above query is not working

Comment: Then you probably have no values in that range. Have you got the numbers right?

Comment: @podiluska  The above query is not working

Comment: @user1716577 "is not working" doesn't help anyone help you. Does it produce an error? (If so, what error?). Does it produce the wrong results (If so, wrong how? Too many, too few, why should/shouldn't certain results be included?) Causes your machine to explode? (Not sure we can help with that one)

Comment: @podiluska  when i have values 12,13,14  my quries are working fine

Comment: @user1716577: do you get any results for `select LogTime 
from timestamplog where LogTime >= 1350468609` or `select LogTime 
from timestamplog where LogTime >= 1350468001` ? If not: then you just don't have those values in your table!

Comment: @marc_s when i use select LogTime from timestamplog where LogTime >= 1350468001
or 
select LogTime from timestamplog where LogTime >= 1350468609 iam getting the resul

Comment: and if you do `select logtime from timestamplog where logtime>=1350468001 and logtime<=135048609` ?

Comment: @ podiluska i tried the above query also, no row are retrived

Comment: @podiluska - there's a typo in your latest query - you're missing a `6`, so the second value is less than the first, as in the OPs question.

Comment: @user1716577 Oops. How about `select logtime from timestamplog where logtime>=1350468001 and logtime<=1350468609 `

Comment: Then there is no data. Can you find a number that you think should be shown?